# A script to find cells with certain values in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this query:

```
    select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name,
       c.column_name
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c
           on c.table_name = t.table_name
           and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.column_name like '%column_name%'
      and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
      and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by t.table_schema;
```

Is there somewhere I can actually search for a specific value and see under which column & table & schema it falls under?

For example,
I would like to search for a value 'WINNER' and find out which columns contain this value (and obviously the table and schema as well)
and the column might be STATUS with value WINNER and under table CUSTOMER and schema ALL_DATA

Can anyone help please?

Comment: you will need to handle a script for this OUTSIDE of redshift. e.g. python.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward way to do this, there is no build-in functionality in any DBMS as far as I know. One way how to do this would be to create SQL which selects all text-like columns and generates another SQL. There is an example:

```
select 'select '''||t.table_schema||''' as table_schema, '''||
   t.table_name||''' as table_name, '''||
   c.column_name||''' as column_name,'||
   ' count(*) as occurrences'
   ' from '||t.table_schema||'.'||t.table_name||
   ' where '||c.column_name||' like ''WINNER'''
   ||' union all '
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c
           on c.table_name = t.table_name
           and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.column_name like '%column_name%'
      and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
      and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and c.data_type = 'character varying'
order by t.table_schema;
```

According to limitations set in query it will generate as much rows as columns you want to search. Copy this result block in your client **(delete 'union all' from last row)** 
and execute. Try to limit rows as much as possible for better performance. Due to columnar data store Redshift will execute this quite effectively, keep in mind that on row-oriented DBMS performance for such approach will be much worse.